# How to get value from json object with java obect mapper

Tags: java, hashmap, jackson

I want to get the value at the field first inside name.

How i can access in this field using HashMap in java

```
 { "payload":{
               "name": {
                      "first": "jean",
                      "last": "bob,
                    },
               "address": {
                    "code": "75",
                    "city": "paris",
                    "country": "France"
                },
 }}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt code, more descriptions of what problems you're having with it and *some* concrete evidence of your prior effort.

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score -1):

Use one of the available Java libraries for handling JSON. E.g. Gson from Guava API. They are pretty straing fw.